# How do I highlight an html element for a few seconds with just html/css?

Tags: html, css

I have FAQs page with a series of questions at the top of the page, and those questions are links to the sections of the page where the answers lie (ex: https://www.unicefusa.org/about/faq).

If you go to the provided link above, you will notice that when you click on a question listed at the top of the page, the page jumps to the section providing the answer. I am wondering how it would be possible to momentarily highlight the section of the page the link jumps to (when clicked). Is it possible to do this with just html/css?

Comment: Yes it is possible. The element that you jumped to is actually selectable by the pseudo-class `:target`, and all you need is to add some CSS animation to it (with `animation-iteration-count` set to 1).

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/yXpjEx

Comment: @Terry Thanks, that did the trick. Adding an animation style to :target works. The only problem is that it doesn't work when the same link is clicked twice. For instance, when you click the link once, the page moves to the relevant section and the animation works. If you scroll back to the link and click it again, it will transition back to the relevant section but without the animation. If you don't click on the same link twice in a row, the animation always works. Not sure how to fix that...

Comment: You will need to use JS to do that, if that is what you want. Basically, the `:target` is only updated when it changes--in other words, if you keep clicking on the same anchor link which gets you to the same target, the animation will not refire.

Answer (score 3):

I just recently learned of @keyframes, which may be exactly what you are looking for. With this and the :target You can use css to make your selected text change color and stay that way for as long as you choose, because it reverts back to with this the element reverts back to it's original css.

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    animation-name: test;
    animation-duration: 4s;
 }

@keyframes test {

  from { background-color: white; }
  to { background-color: red; }
}
```

Here is a link to the example https://jsfiddle.net/Arparas/oe7twew8/

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes test {
  
      from {background-color: white;}
      to {background-color: red;}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is Information</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry css :target selector rocks well for this

Answer (score 0):

If you add a target section id and "a:focus" in css for the link, it will show the color that you added on css for a moment. You can see it if you click and hold the link.
eg:
a:focus {
`color: yellow;`
}